# problem getting jquery to run

Tags: javascript, jquery

This problem is being a real ballache. Normally i dont have any problems getting jquery to run.

I am running a asp web site with c#.

Here is the html generated by the page. When i click the button with id test i get the error below.

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;
>   GTB7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;
>   .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Wed, 15
>   Jun 2011 17:08:03 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support this
>   property or method Line: 236 Char: 1
>   Code: 0 URI:
>   http://localhost:53294/FluidataPortal/connections/macRequest.aspx

--HTML

Just showing the relevent html for clarity. I can show the full if needed

```
<button id="test" onclick="test()">
Click me to test
</button>
```

--Javascript

```
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2011, John Resig
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 * Copyright 2011, The Dojo Foundation
 * Released under the MIT, BSD, and GPL Licenses.
 *
 * Date: Mon May 2 13:50:00 2011 -0400
 */
JQUERY CODE. REMOVED FOR CLARITY

function test() {

    if (!busy) {
        $.get("ajax/RequestMac.aspx?user=Tomsquires&dsl=123", function(response, status, xhr) {
            alert(response);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug to set breakpoints and step through your JS to see where the error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including your jQuery after your JavaScript.

jQuery needs to be loaded **BEFORE** your JavaScript.

---

**EDIT:**

The OP's original HTML showed an Includes to an external JS file being loaded before his jQuery includes.

I put mine at the bottom of the `<body>` element like this...

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ajax/jquery/myCustom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        //<![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //  my code
            });
        //]]>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**[HERE is why.](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/)**

Comment: To clarify, you should not be adding JS code in the jquery.js file, you should have something like

`<script ... src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script ... src="myscript.js"></script>`

Comment: @Colin:  I agree.  Also, in his original post, he was calling an Includes to an external JavaScript before he was calling the jQuery Includes.