# Prettyphoto not working in IE7?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, include, lightbox

Prettyphoto jquery doesn't seem to be working in ie7 I've tried placing the script in different areas within the code/head, but still get a none support warning, so I've put it in a separate js file and again its still not working in ie7? Any help please, thanks T

the code is here: http://www.designford.co.uk/web.html

Answer (score 1):

You are loading PrettyPhoto twice...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
```

I am also not sure why you need the `charset="utf-8"` within the JS Includes.

You have a whole bunch of [Validation Errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.designford.co.uk/web.html#!prettyPhoto%5B%5D/1/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) too.

---

**EDIT:**

Also see [the link](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/) at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361564/problem-getting-jquery-to-run/6361633#6361633) about the best place to insert your JS Includes.

Comment: Woops, thats what happens when quickly changing things around, I'll validate it and see if it clears anything anything up, thanks

Comment: It seems to be the border"0" and the rel="prettyphoto[]" that validator is picking out, and they normally don't mess things up?

Comment: @Anthony:  I use prettyPhoto and have no trouble getting it to validate.  I don't see the `border` anyplace in your validation results.  Instead of `rel=`, you can use `class="prettyPhoto"` and change your jQuery selector to `$("a.prettyPhoto")`.  That should work too.

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and its not worked so reverted back, I use prettyphoto as well and have tried a few things now, but its still not happing in 7 yet - thinking of maybe using a different light box and rebuilding that section of the page, but this one should work?

Comment: @Anthony:  Mine works fine in all versions of IE.  Setup a test page:  Duplicate the page, remove all extraneous code/plugins leaving only prettyPhoto, then try it.  Also, have you updated the live page so I can see where you're at now with this?

Comment: @Anthony: The page you have posted in your question still shows 48 validation errors.

Comment: @Anthony: Also, did you see my edits regarding the placement of your Javascript within the page?  Everything will load and run better if you take that advice.  It's also easier to troubleshoot when it's all in one place.

Comment: Hi, I've cleared most of the errors now and put these at the foot of the page: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prettyc.js"></script>
</body>
</html> One thing I have noticed is that its no longer a gallery (no option to go left or right now, in ff anyway...?

Comment: @Anthony:  Go back a few comments.  Sometimes it's easier to start over with just the basic functionality and build it up from there.

Comment: Think thats the best thing to do, bed time now, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

I was having an issue with this too, and I solved it just by removing a comma at the end of my prettyPhotto options. Different from other browsers, IE7 shows an JS error when you leave a comma at the last item. Hope this helps.